# C# Webbrowser navigation question

Tags: c#, browser

Hello im trying to log into a site using a WebBrowser control currently its working perfectly at logging in, but when I go to a different page of the site programmaticly by using navigate or making the WebBrowser click on the link im not logged in any more? Im guessing it has something to do with cookies or something but haven't been able to find anything on Google of how to get this to work.

```
   HtmlElement content = this.wb.Document.GetElementById("content");
   HtmlElement username = content.Document.All["username"];
   username.SetAttribute("value", "Username");
   HtmlElement pass = content.Document.All["password"];
   pass.SetAttribute("value", "Password");
   HtmlElement goButton = content.Document.All["submit"];
   goButton.Focus();
   SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Is currently what I have.
Ah hell now that I tried to use this it didn't work correctly now anyway to get a button from what text it has in it and not what style it is also?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will work with firefox, but cannot to work on IE. So, pls modify your code as below. Hope that helps :)

```
HtmlElement content = this.wb.Document.GetElementById("content");
HtmlElement username = content.Document.All["username"];
username.SetAttribute("value", "Username");
HtmlElement pass = content.Document.All["password"];
pass.SetAttribute("value", "Password");  

HtmlElementCollection htmlCol = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement el in htmlCol)
{
    if ((el.Name == "submit") && (el.GetAttribute("value") == "Value of submit button"))
    {
       el.InvokeMember("click");
       break;
    }
}
```